# getElementByClass node innerHTML is updated, but not in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have this following DOM structure inside the body of my document:

```
<body>

<div id="spin"></div>
<div class="Main"></div>

<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>

</body>
```

I am having a hard time trying to update the HTML of class='Main' . The code i'm using is

```
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('Main');
selector.innerHTML = '<h1>This</h1>'
```

The strange thing is that if I inspect

```
selector.innerHTML
```

inside of the chrome console it is updated to the html, but the DOM nor my view is updated.

Comment: `selector` is referencing a collection of nodes, not a single node. You need to operate on them individually. So all you've done is added a new property to the collection. This stores the string you provided, but does nothing more.

Comment: Thanks! I chose the correct one with selector[0].innerHTML

Comment: FYI, `document.querySelectorAll(".Main")` has better browser support overall, and if you only need the first element, then `document.querySelector(".Main")` will give you the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('Main');
```

returns you a set of nodes. So doing

```
selector.innerHTML = '<h1>This</h1>'
```

will have no effect on the dom. It'll only change the JavaScript object containing the nodes.

You can instead do this:

```
selector[0].innerHTML = '<h1>This</h1>'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't use `innerHTML` *ever*.

It's a proprietary Microsoft JScript method, yeah it's been grandfathered in to a spec somewhere but that doesn't mean you should use it. The problem is that `innerHTML` treats code as text, not code. So it doesn't serialize the code in to the DOM, it just dumps a bunch of text and each rendering engine has to figure out what to do with it.

```
alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementsByClassName('Main')));
```

Also don't capitalize elements, attributes and values as it's a lax practice. Strict code is good code, you'll always know what to expect and *that* is how you get things done now instead of three days from later.